# Bash - Permission denied error when logging to /var/log/<file-name>

Tags: bash, permissions, cron

For an application I want to store specific data on a data recovery server. On the application and DR server I created a user `test1` and copied the public key from application server user `test1` to DR user `test1`'s authorized_keys file. User `test1` is added to the wheel group.

I set permission on `drwxr-xr-x /var/log`

I then created a cron job to rsync the data from the application server to the DR server:

```
sudo rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /home/test1/.ssh/my-ssh-key" /var/nfsshare/ test1@10.10.10.10:/var/nfsshare > /var/log/nfs_cron-$(date +\%m-\%d-\%Y).log
```

When the cron executes I get the following error:

> /bin/sh: /var/log/nfs_cron-08-26-2019.log: Permission denied

However, when I try to create a file manually it creates the file successfully.

```
sudo touch /var/log/test.txt
```

which creates the file as:

```
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 test1 test1 0 Aug 26 12:28 test.txt
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a directory and give permission to this user or you can use redirection/tee to write the log file.

For example using ACL:
    mkdir -p /var/log/my_app/
    setfacl -Rm g:MY_GROUP_ID:rwx /var/log/my_app/

The `setfacl` command is to setup ACL.

`-R` -> It's to be recursive and setup the ACL to all subfolder

`-m` -> It's to modify the ACL

`g`or`u`  -> It's to define the group or user

`rwx` -> It's the permission to setup for the group/user

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#SETFACLREF

---

Another way is using redirection/tee. With redirection, you can "filter" what you want log into the file. For example:

Log and/or concatenate just in case of success

```
ls -lZ /tmp/myfile >> /var/log/mylog
```

Log everything (Sending stderr to stdout and writing into the same file)

```
ls -lZ /tmp/myfile >> /var/log/mylog 2>&1
```

or just use `&>`

```
ls -lZ /tmp/myfile &> /var/log/mylog
```

If you don't have permission to write on the destination file/directory, you can use `tee` to write. For example, appending (`-a`) and writing into the file `/var/log/mylog`.

```
ls -lZ /tmp/myfile | sudo tee -a /var/log/mylog
```

You can find some other examples and a better explanation in here:

https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial

https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the redirection is done by the user calling sudo, rather than by the sudo itself.

```
cmd > file
```

creates `file` before launching `cmd`, which means in your case that the regular user is trying to create the log, and then pass its filehandle to `sudo` to write to.

To confirm my theory, try this:

```
sudo echo test > /var/log/test.txt
```

and you should get the same error message.

You have to pass the filename to the command so that it is created by the program called by `sudo`. In your case, you could accomplish this by wrapping the whole thing into a script, for example.

Comment: Hi @joanis, I tried your recommendation and yes I got the same error. I have an additional, similar cronjob to run. So, I guess I will create a file for each and reference the files in the cronjob.     Thank you for your info.